# getting remote drivernodes using "devcon drivernodes"

Tags: vbscript, devcon

I was trying to get the below information related to the drivers.

Name, INFFile, Vendor, Version, Description, and Date.

All the information i could find it using the below command.

"devcon drivernodes"

But this is only working in local machine. (Checked with MSDN and came to know that we cannot get the remote machine details with this command.

Do we have any other utility / way to get the mentioned details from a remote computer?

I am capturing all the details using VBScript (using .exec method and stdout.readline method)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
wmic /node:computerlist.txt sysdriver get /format:list
```

Computerlist.txt is a list of IP addresses or computernames.

For local computer

```
wmic sysdriver get /format:list
```

See `wmic /?` (for a partial list of what's available), `wmic sysdriver get /?`, and `wmic /format /?`.

**EDIT**

To get file versions, if a file has one. Note backslashes have to be doubled.

*Filever.bat filename*

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"
```

To start a program (it will be invisible on remote computers)

```
wmic process call create c:\\windows\\notepad.exe
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found this is very useful utility. But the only problem is, I am not able to get the Driver version, other than that all the details are available, and that too in desired format :)